# object arr[i] to ASCII value (int)

Tags: c#

I have object array in loop, and want to get for each element it's ASCII value as integer for comparison, How I can do that?

```
       for (int i = 0; i < str.Length; i++)
        {

            for (int j = 0; j < Encrypt.values.Length; j++)
            {
                if (Convert.ToInt32(((char)str[i])) >= 49 && Convert.ToInt32(((char)str[i])) <= 57)
                {
                    if (str[i].Equals(Encrypt.values[j]))
                        str[i] = Encrypt.alp[j];
                }
            }
        }
```

Comment: What is the actual type of the array members? Why are you using `Object[]` instead of `String[]`?

Comment: I have other types there, so keeping them in object, and doing comparison for taking needed types

Comment: "object array"? What would be "ASCII value" for instance of `Control` class or `List<double>` or even simple `double` value?

Comment: "and doing comparison for taking needed types" - like `Enumerable.OfType<TypeIWant>` or `item is TypeIWant` ?

Comment: That's why I'm trying to go through the elements that are only char,

Comment: Please provide type of `str` in you sample - looks like your text in your post is totally random... Possibly you are looking for characters of a string that are digits and trying to re-map digits with are dictionary...

Comment: object[] str , at this moment when i'm trying to do so, in str are onli chars

Comment: @Arman Use Linq then: `objectArray.OfType<Char>().Select( c => (Int32)c ).ToArray();`.

Answer (score 0):

`char` and `int` are in fact almost the same, they just have another representation. `char` will give you the ASCII value at a specific position in the ASCII table. It uses the integer value stored in the actual data type for that. That's why it is save to do:

```
(int)str[i]
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you are trying to pick digits from a string and replace them with "encrypted" versions.

Regular expression are perfect fit for selecting particular set of digits from text - i.e. in this case `\d` - single "digit" character.

Sample shows regular expression to pick single digit (`\d`) and usage of [Regex.Replace](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ht1sxswy%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) to convert all matches into new values:

```
string str = "aaaa 0 bbbb"; 
var encryptionMap = new Dictionary<char, string>{{'0', "9"}}; // incomplete
string withEncryptedDigits = Regex.Replace(str, @"\d", 
      match => encryptionMap[match.Value[0]]);
Console.WriteLine(withEncryptedDigits);
```

---

If indeed `str` is array of objects (very cleaver variable name to hide meaning of it) you can filter values with `is`:

```
for (int i = 0; i < objectArray.Length; i++)
{
    if (objectArray[i] is char)
    {
        int charCode = (int)(char)(objectArray[i]);
        ....
    }
}
```

Notes:

- to get "char code as integer" you need double cast - first to actual type of element (`(char)`) and than convert to integer type (`(int)`). Otherwise you'll get runtime exception about type mismatch (can't cast object of type `char` to `int`).
- ASCII is very small subset of all characters supported by .Net. Make sure to have conditions that filter out subset you need.

Comment: Look, I'm getting in object str[]{2,4,8,6,4,7,d}; like this, so in this step I need take and change 2,4,8,6,4,7 by other values and stay d as it is, any ideas?

Comment: how get str[0]'s ascii valu to check if it is number or it isn't?

Comment: `str[]{2,4,8,6,4,7,d}` have *no* characters - it is list of integers and one variable named `d`. Please make sure to edit your post with actual code. I believe my answer covers most of the possible interpretations of your question.